# Какая последовательность действий в формуле?

Tags: java, инкремент

Почему `а=70`?? Никак не могу подобрать порядок производимых действий в формуле:

```
int i = 1;
int a = 3+i+6*++i*5^12>>1; 
System.out.println(i); //2
System.out.println(a); //70
```

Comment: Следует указать язык программирования. В разных языках последовательность вычисления выражений может отличаться и приводить к разным результатам.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Смотрим на [таблицу приоритета операций](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) и расставляем скобки в соответствии с этими приоритетами, учитывая что операции одинакового приоритета выполняются слева направо.

Наименьшим приоритетом среди имеющихся обладает оператор "исключающее или" (xor) `^`, поэтому выражение эквивалентно следующему:

```
a = (3 + i + 6 * ++i * 5) ^ (12 >> 1);
```

Далее будет вычислено выражение в первых скобках, т.е.:

```
3 + i + 6 * ++i * 5
```

Вычислено он будет следующим образом:

```
1) 3
2) [_1_] + i == 4
3) 6
4) ++i == 2 и i := 2
5) [_3_] * [_4_] == 6 * 2 == 12
6) [_5_] * 5 == 12 * 5 == 60
7) [_2_] + [_6_] == 4 + 60 == 64
```

(Здесь `[_N_]` - значение, вычисленное на шаге `N`.)

Далее вычисляется

```
12 >> 1 == 6
```

и, наконец,

```
a = 64 ^ 6 = 70
```

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из приоритетов операторов, порядок будет таким:

1) ++

2) *

3) +

4) >>

5) ^

6) =

Посмотрим, как выглядит последовательное выполнение операторов в приведенном коде:

1) 3+1+6*2*5^12>>1 (i после инкремента равно 2)

2) 3+1+12*5^12>>1

3) 3+1+60^12>>1

4) 4+60^12>>1

5) 64^12>>1

6) 64^6

7) 70

8) ну, и оператор =

Как видим, всё верно, i = 2, a = 70

Comment: Спасибо! уже много версий прокручивал в голове, но все таки вопрос у меня остался, касательно таблицы приоритетов, приведу пример:
1+2*3=7, 1е действие с которого начинает составлятся ответ - умножение.. Вот и в моем вопросе 1е действие вы указали - это инкремент,  с него машина и начинает состовлять ответ,  "и" становится 2. Но раз "и" равняется 2, почему дальше идет строка:
`3+1+12*5^12>>1` а не `3+2!!!+12*5^12>>1`

Comment: @jack В примере `1+2*3` первое действие - вычисление выражения `1`, второе - выражения `2`, третье - выражения `3`, четвёртое - перемножение второго и третьего, пятое - сложение первого и четвёртого.